# Use Decimate modifier as a realtime LOD generator

Tags: python, rendering, modifiers

I have a very dense scene and I need the objects to vary their polycount in realtime based on camera distance. The idea is to keep objects about 20% (0.2000) of the original polycount when the camera is far and 100% (1.000) when near.

I'm trying to do this with a driver connected to the Decimate modifier Ratio value.

The thing is.. I have no idea how to set this!

I'm trying this solution because my graphics card go out of memory. Will the Decimate modifier help reduce the card memory load?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To add a driver to the Decimate Modifier's Ration value, right click on it and choose 'Add Driver'. The slider will turn purple.

[image: Driver on Decimate Modifier]

Go to the Graph Editor and choose the Drivers context.

[image: Drivers context]

For the driver Type choose Distance.

For one object choose your Camera, and for the other your object with the modifier on it. Name your variable something that makes sense to you (mine is 'dist'). For the scripted expression you can use `1/(dist/8)` for example and the Ratio value will *decrease* as the distance *increases*.

You can replace `8` with a lower number for less distance required for decimation, or a higher number for more distance required.

[image: Driver settings]

As for setting a minimum of 0.2, I don't know how you could do that, but I bet if you look in the Python documentation or maybe ask on Stack Overflow you can find out how to write that specific expression.

[image]

Comment: would this reduce the gpu viewport memory usage? Maybe adding the driver to the display state enum would do that, meaning that when zoomed out, you see only the bounding box, zoomed in the detail returns?

Comment: @aliasguru I have no reason to believe this approach would reduce GPU usage for the viewport. If anything, it will increase it because the decimation calculations will need to be recalculated in realtime. It is definitely *not* a viable solution for enhancing viewport performance. In retrospect I should have simply answered OP by saying "don't do this". There are better ways to speed up the viewport, such as using the Mask Modifier on parts of objects you don't need to be visible, and moving unnecessary objects to other layers - viewport performance is a broad topic.

Comment: that's what i thought, and there is also no simple solution without knowing the specific scene. if there's subsurf modifiers, one could use the simplify feature of blender in the scene tab, but even there, the crashes would remain. bounding box display might really be the only choice until 2.8 of course :)