# Possible to automatically decimate geometry based on distance to save ram?

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to decimate based on distance from camera in cycles?  Would save a ton of VRAM.

Comment: You can drive the collapse distance for decimation with a vertex group. Create a spherical gradient vertex group (with a big brush) with your camera in the center.

Comment: so will the vertex weight value act as a multiplier for the decimation ratio/factor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Decimate modifier as a realtime LOD generator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51942/use-decimate-modifier-as-a-realtime-lod-generator)