# Merge vertices by distance modifier

Tags: modeling

Novice question, is there a modifier that merges a mesh vertices based on the distance? For example, if you create a cylinder bending a subdivided plane with the SimpleDeform modifier, how do you weld the vertices along the seam? The decimate modifier looks like it can weld vertices between close edgeloops but not along the seam. Clearly one could collapse the modifier stack and remove doubles, but that not an option in my case since I want to keep working non-destructively.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51942/use-decimate-modifier-as-a-realtime-lod-generator

Comment: That example uses the distance between the camera and the mesh to drive the "collapse" algorithm. What I'm looking for is the distance between the vertices. Like the "remove duplicates" algorithm, but as modifier.

Answer (score 3):

While I can't remember if it existed 2 years and 8 months ago, Blender now has a Weld modifier which does exactly what you're asking.