# Is it possible to write a script that changes multiresolution based on a camera distance?

Tags: python, scripting, camera

I am trying to create a relativly big scene for my computer and when I try to render blender gives a cuda error, but if I the multires resolution on the objects it is rendering, because this is going to be short film project, my scene is going to be rendered from everywhere. I wonder if it is possible to write a script changing the multiresuliton proporties based on camera distance? I think this is going to help for cuda error.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51942/use-decimate-modifier-as-a-realtime-lod-generator

Comment: thank you for your answer, i know this technique but i think driver solution is going to slow my scene even more...